# Exposing state of object to be changed by certain classes

Tags: c#

I have a class, LibrarySource, that contains the path of a remote location, and it's state. SourceState is an enum that can be either New, Updating or Ready.

```
public class LibrarySource {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public SourceState State { get; }
}
```

I have another class, Synchroniser, that will deal with synchronising the data found at the source to a local directory, while also updating the state of the LibrarySource object at certain stages of the operation.

```
public class Synchroniser {

    LibrarySource _librarySource;

    public Synchroniser(LibrarySource source){
        _librarySource = source;
    }

    public Task SyncAsync(){
        // At start of sync, set _librarySource.State = Updating
        // At end of sync, set _librarySource.State = Ready
    }
}
```

When a new source is added the State will equal New, when it is synchronising it will equal Updating and when it is ready for use it will be Ready.

How should the Synchroniser communicate to the LibrarySource that it should change its state? I could expose the set of the State property, but this does not feel right.

Edit:

To make clear, a class should only be allowed to change the State of the LibrarySource if explicitly stated, I would like to prevent unwanted changes to the state.

Can this be accomplished in a clean manner, or is it easier to expose the set; and deal with the consequences?

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: You mean you could expose the `set` of the `State` property?

Comment: As I said I tried exposing the set; on the State property, but this then allows any class to set the state of the LibrarySource object, which I think should not happen.

Comment: There is only one Synchroniser instance per LibrarySource instance?

Comment: @rene Yes there will only be one instance of a Synchroniser per LibrarySource at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I realised I required a state machine that is able to maintain the state while preventing undefined state changes.

I went with [Stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Synchroniser controls the state and thus the value. Seems appropriate to expose setter.
What is in your mind?

Another way is to provide functions in `LibrarySource` class that shall be invoked to update itself, meaning LibrarySource being made responsible to update itself. Just that it's updation be scheduled by Synchroniser.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is limit access to the property. There are multiple ways to approach this: **access modifiers** and **nested classes**.

- If you use the `internal` access modifier, it will only be accessible from within the same assembly (= project in Visual Studio). I'm note sure if this fits the requirements of your question, as I am not sure how your projects are set up. But this is the easiest approach to severely limit access to properties.
- You can also use the `protected` modifier, but this only exposes the protery to derived classes. Your code sample does not use inheritance between `LibrarySource` and `Synchronizer`, so this will not work for your current case.
- If you set a property to `private`, it can be accessed from **within** that class. If you then define your `Synchronizer` class **inside** your `LibrarySource` class (thus making a nested class), the nested class will be able to access the private properties of its "root" class.

Code example for the third option:

```
public class LibrarySource 
{    
    public string Path { get; set; }  
    private SourceState State { get; }

    public class Synchroniser 
    {
        LibrarySource _librarySource;

        public Synchroniser(LibrarySource source){
            _librarySource = source;
        }

        public Task SyncAsync(){
            // At start of sync, set _librarySource.State = Updating
            // At end of sync, set _librarySource.State = Ready
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be the best solution for what you want to achieve.

---

**Edit**

The `Synchronizer` class will still need to be supplied with a reference to the correct `LibrarySource` object, just like you were already doing. By nesting the classes, nothing has changed about how you work with the classes.

You can redesign this so that every `LibrarySource` has its own `Synchronizer` property (thus forgoing the need for making a direct reference), but this is out of scope for the current question.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an explicit backing field for the State property e.g.

```
public class LibrarySource {
    private SourceState _state;

    public string Path { get; set; }
    public SourceState State { get { return _state; } }
}
```

You can have Synchroniser use reflection to update the backing field value at the appropriate times.

Comment: `SourceState` is presumably a class, thus a reference type. Your code will allow **every** external caller to change the values of the properties of `State` (though they will not be able to change the `State` object reference itself)

Comment: @Flater You may be correct, but the assumption I made was that it is an enum.

Comment: The SourceState is in fact an enum, I have edited my question with this info. Is using using reflection to edit the backing field acceptable?

Comment: @bic: That's a difficult question to answer. It works, which is enough for some to consider it acceptable. Others will not like using reflection in cases where reflection can be avoided (it can be used to force situations and create dirty fixes for problems that should instead call for a redesign). As to your specific question, there is nothing preventing other parts of your code from also using reflection, so it does somewhat miss the point of your question.

Comment: Acceptable to whom? Only you can answer that. There is nothing inherently wrong with using reflection to update unexposed fields. The main consideration is that there is some overhead in reflection so, in a high performance application there would be some performance impact.